# what would be a good way to implement List.scani, in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a situation where I'm parsing a file and I need to know both:

- the current line
- the previous line

before the previous line requirements, I was doing something like:

```
myData
|> List.mapi (fun i data -> parse i data)
```

but now I need access to the previous line, so scan is ideal for that, but then I loose the index.

so, I need a List.scani function :) is it something that could be built easily in an idiomatic way?

Comment: Have you considered using `List.index` combined with `List.pairwise`?

Comment: @HenrikHansen, no, I didn't think of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define scani as follows:

```
let scani (f:int->'S->'T->'S) (state:'S) (list:'T list) = 
    list
    |>List.scan (fun (i,s) x -> (i+1,f i s x)) (0,state)
    |>List.map snd
```

Creating a tuple with the original state and a counter initialized with `(0,state)`.  The state is manipulated as usual with the folder function f (that now takes an extra i parameter) and the counter incremented by one. Finally, we remove the counter from the state by taking the second element of the state.

You could use it as follows, where i is the index, s is the state, and x the element.

```
[1;2;3]
|> scani (fun i s x -> s + i*x) 0
|> should equal [0;0;2;8]
```

Answer (score 3):

It may not be the most efficient way to do it, but it seems to work (I called it scanl given that you want access to the previous element, or line):

```
let scanl f s l =
    List.scan (fun (acc,elem0) elem1 -> (f acc elem0 elem1),elem1) (s,List.head l) l
    |> List.map fst
```

Examples of usage:

```
let l = [1..5]

scanl (fun acc elem0 elem1 -> elem0,elem1) (0,0) l
//result: [(0, 0); (1, 1); (1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 5)]
```

The usual List.scan would give this:

```
List.scan (fun acc elem -> elem) 0 l
//result [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```